# How to set Eve resource and item calls to go through custom made deserialize function

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, eve

I can't create my API to return datefields in JSON format. So I had to create a function to serialize it. dump_datetime function does that for me.
My problem now is that, I don't know how to make my resource calls run the dump_datetime call whenever I throw a GET Resource request.

Let's say we have a resource Users which has a "birthdate" attribute.  How do I make "birthdate" attribute to go through the dump_datetime() function?

```
Since in Eve you could already get the item call by  http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/id
```

How do I set the get call to go through the dump_datetime?

Is my question clear?

Below is an example of a custom function using the deserialize function I made. I just want to know how to make it work in Eve Item and Resource calls.

```
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
def dump_datetime(value):
    """Deserialize datetime object into string form for JSON processing."""
    if value is None:
        return None
    return value.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test_mail():
  bdate = datetime.datetime.strptime( '19900914', "%Y%m%d").date()
  b = dump_datetime(bdate)
  return jsonify(results = b)
```

UPDATE:
SHOULD I EDIT THE /var/www/healthyoptions-middleware/eve/methods/get.py File and run the serialize function for attributes that need serializing?????

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, all you need is to use event hooks. A post-request hook on the GET method and the resource you want should do the trick; e.g. `on_post_GET_<resource_name> = deserializing_function`. Alternatively, you can hook on database requests, such as on_fetched_resource_.

From the documentation:

> When a GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE method has been executed, both a
>   on_post_ and on_post__ event is raised. You
>   can subscribe to these events with multiple callback functions.
>   Callbacks will receive the resource accessed, original flask.request
>   object and the response payload.
>
> Database event hooks work like request event hooks. These events are fired before and after a database action.

http://python-eve.org/features.html#event-hooks